# How do I fix the Error code 2001 in MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access

I receive this error message after I run this submacro:

```
[Forms]![Statistics]![Text53], DCount("[Report Number]","[qSTATS1]","[Material Engineer or Plant#]='Kleinfeld'")
```

[Macro Single Step Error Message, Code: 2001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Fhn.png)

Please assist.

Comment: I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Macro single step window does not show error message, only number. Why are you saving aggregate data?

Comment: What does saving aggregate data mean?

Comment: DCount is a domain aggregate function. Saving aggregate data is usually a bad idea.  Google it.

Comment: If you don't know definition of 'aggregate data', maybe this will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_data. SetValue method is setting value of a control and if that control is bound to field then you are saving aggregate data.

Comment: I think that this is  the only way for my data to populate on a form supported by a date query.

Comment: Did you mean 'data' query? No, this is not the only way to populate a form. DCount() function can be used in textbox ControlSource. Again, seems your code attempts to save value to field, not just 'populate a form'.